# Is Behavior a Comonad?

Tags: haskell, frp, purescript, category-theory

Conal Elliott talks about Streams and Comonads here: http://conal.net/blog/posts/sequences-streams-and-segments

However, he doesn't mention Behavior directly. So.. is Behavior a Comonad, and if so - what does that mean practically?

For starters - I suppose Behavior can provide the `extend` and `extract` functions. The only way I see that working is if it samples the value at a specific moment in time.

Is that what Comonad would mean for Behavior? That it allows one to "fork and freeze" a Behavior?

In other words - if we have a Behavior that has these values over time: `A,B,C,D,...` we could `extend` it at the time where it's `B`, and get a new Behavior which contains `B` indefinitely (which is useful - since we could then `lift` or `map` it etc.)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a pure function if the result depends upon the time of the call

Comment: Very good point! :D

Comment: It is pure in the sense that the time is a pure value. While `now` is in the `IO` monad, a particular time in the past or future is a pure value.

Comment: @BobDalgleish But we don't pass in the time as an argument

Comment: @Bergi Have a read of section 2 of [_Push-Pull FRP_](http://conal.net/papers/push-pull-frp/push-pull-frp.pdf). `Behaviour a` denotes `Time -> a`, in the sense that a `Behaviour` can be sampled at any time and sampling a `Behaviour` has no side-effects. `Time -> a` is a model, not the actual implementation, but it tells you a lot about how `Behaviour`s compose. The fact that the `Time` is handled implicitly by the framework doesn't change the model, much as using a parser combinator library to handle leftovers and backtracking doesn't change the `String -> [(a, String)]` model.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson I know Push-Pull FRP, but I don't see how you can write a function `extract :: (Time -> a) -> a` without an impure (or useless?) construction of a Time value

Comment: @Bergi -∞ (ie the behaviour's initial value) would seem like a natural choice. No idea whether that can be efficiently implemented

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson yeah, that might work (with `duplicate` mapping the behaviour to a behaviour of itself with all past values forgotten).

Comment: Not in the standard semantics, but there was some exploration of *relative-time* FRP for a bit, in which `Behavior` is a comonad (& `extract` samples at time 0).

Answer (score 3):

`Behavior a` is isomorphic to `(Time -> a)`.  The definitions Conal gives in the section of that post "Adding continuity" match those in the [comonad package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5.0.4/docs/src/Control.Comonad.html#line-170).

It is not obvious to me how to make time a Monoid.  Several Monoid instances are possible, but are any useful?  Conal's post on [future values](http://conal.net/blog/posts/future-values) suggests that the `Max` is a useful Monoid for working with time.

This works out that `extract @Behavior` gives the value at the earliest possible time, and `duplicate @Behavior` gives the value at the later of the two times.  I can see both of those being useful.  Perhaps there are other useful Monoids also?